# Unable to access camera through browser

Tags: python, ssh, camera, web-server, web-interface

I am writing a Python CGI script that I want to run on my laptop's browser. This script will SSH into two Pis, and give the command to take a photo. The server hosting this script is on one of the Pis that I want to SSH into, and that Pi also is acting as an access point for the other Pi and my laptop to connect to (everything is a LAN, not connected to the Internet).

I am successfully able to run this script on my laptop's browser to run simple commands like `ls -l` on both Pis and print out the results for both on the browser. But, I ultimately want to be able to give the `raspistill` command to both Pis. When I do this, only the Pi with the server is taking the image, but the other Pi is not. I assume it's because permissions aren't set properly for the server (I tried running the commands as `sudo` but still no luck). However, if I run the same script on a Python IDLE it works fine. Can somebody help me identify the issue?

Here is my script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

from pssh import ParallelSSHClient
import cgi

print("Content-Type: text/plain\r\n")
print("\r\n ")

host = ['172.24.1.1','172.24.1.112']
user = 'XXXX'
password = 'XXXX'
client = ParallelSSHClient(host, user, password)

output = client.run_command('raspistill -o test.jpg', sudo=True)

// AMENDMENT:
for line in output['172.24.1.1'].stdout:   //also works with other IP addr.
    print(line)
```

AMENDMENT:
Apparently, if I output anything from the `stdout`, both pictures are taken and show up in the respective directories. I now suspect this might be a issue with the pssh package I am using. It might be waiting for me output something, but I don't know why? Does anyone know why this might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thoroughly reading through the documentation for the `pssh` module, my problem had to do with the exit codes and how they are handled.

The documentation about `run_command` states that:

> function will return after connection and authentication establishment and after commands have been sent to successfully established SSH channels.

And as a result:

> Because of this, exit codes will not be immediately available even for
>   commands that exit immediately.

Initially, I was just blindly running the `run_command` expecting the commands to finish, but it turns out I need to get the exit codes to truly finish the processes the commands are running. The documentations states a couple of ways to do this:

> At least one of
>
> - Iterating over stdout/stderr to completion
> - Calling `client.join(output)` is necessary to cause `parallel-ssh` to    wait for commands to finish and be able to gather exit codes.

This is why in my amendment to the code, where I was outputting from stdout, the commands seemed to work properly.